# VisualStudio Visual C# DataReceived Firing Erratically (Receiving Data From Arduino)

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program in C# in VisualStudio. The basic way it works is that I have my device sampling at 250 samples per second (21 byte packets), relaying data to a Teensy 3.2 which is then relaying it to the computer via USB for processing.

I'm using serialPort_DataReceived to figure out when I received data, with ReceivedBytesThreshold set to 8. If I'm understanding this correctly, whenever it receives at least 8 bytes, it fires the serialPort.DataReceived event and go from there. However, what happens with my program is it fires after it receives 4095 bytes, then it fires after 1 byte, then after 4095 etc.

Also, I swapped out the Teensy for an Arduino Due. In this case it's a lot more stable, firing after every packet as expected, with the exception of the weird 1 byte packets firing after 4095 bytes have been sent. If I crank up the device to 8000 samples per second (the target rate) I start getting serialPort.DataReceived firing after every 3 packets or so. I figured it was the speed of the Arduino slowing it down, which is why I switched to the Teensy, as it runs a lot faster.

I know the sampling device is running fine, as I have three of them and swapping them out provides the same result, and they're designed to handle up to 16000 samples per second. Likewise, I used Realterm to view the incoming data stream and it seems to be constant, and not chunks, so I figure its something in my code. The relevant bits are below.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        serialPort1.PortName = "COM13";
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 115200;
        serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
        serialPort1.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 21;
        serialPort1.RtsEnable = true;
        serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
        serialPort1.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.XOnXOff;
    }
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[serialPort1.ReadBufferSize];
        int bytesRead = serialPort1.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        RxString = BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        fixedString = RxString.Replace("-", "");
        file.WriteLine(fixedString);
        file.WriteLine("THIS IS A TEST");
        this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(graph)); 
        this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
    }
```

Here are some images of the output.
Teensy: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1b4J.png
Due: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK2ar.png

Note for this the header is B6B0C0

Comment: What is the 1 byte being sent after the 4095, For example, I know that if an EOF is sent you will get an event.

Comment: It's random when using the Teensy, pretty consistently the first byte of the header when using the Arduino Due. I'm going to add some screenshots to the question to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Serial ports are pretty slow compared to most other hardware in your computer. You cannot rely on receiving all data sent in one go. Serial really has no concept of 'packets', or any indivisible unit larger than a byte.

It is not uncommon to receive partial messages. And as you see, how data is broken up can vary. You may send 1000 bytes in on one side, and it may come as 500 and 500 on the other side. That's pretty normal. If you look at serial protocols, many implement delimiters (often a 0 byte) and byte-length is part of the content. That helps the user determine what constitutes a whole message.

So to put it at a high level: You need to know when a message starts, and how long it will be. If you don't have a complete message, you need to save your data and wait for more, and repeat until you do have a whole message. You cannot expect to just shove in the result of converting a string to bytes, and expect it to come out whole and readily convertible back to a string on the other end.

Comment: Oh I know that, I have a header on the message and I'm just going to parse the string and split it into packets using that. I haven't implemented it yet. My bigger concern is why it isn't triggering the DataReceived event until the buffer is full (which i assume is happening), then triggering it twice, resulting in one super long string and one one byte string.

Comment: That is a bit odd then.  Can you monitor `serialPort1.BytesToRead`? Would help identify whether the event is just not firing or if the data is just being slowly flushed somewhere else along the line.

Comment: serialPort1.BytesToRead is returning 0 when only one byte is being returned and 4095 when it's returning the giant chunk of data. I just did it quick and dirty so it prints out BytesToRead, the string and then the THIS IS A TEST and the result is here http://i.imgur.com/KzFxGtM.png

Comment: Can you put the output of `BytesToRead` in a timer or something other than the event? Basically, you just want to see if it is climbing above your `ReceivedBytesThreshold` without triggering the `DataReceived` event. If it *is*, that is likely a bug within `SerialPort`, I would guess. If it is *not*, then there may be some flushing issues in your serial driver or one of the devices.

Comment: Yeah sure, I'll edit this comment in like 15 minutes, just gonna go grab lunch.

Comment: Oh editing is only allowed within 5 minutes, TIL. Anyways I did that and it kept returning 0 everywhere. When I printed out bytestoread right before serial read though, it started at 4096 (as expected), then after a while hit 8192, then 12288 etc. Just kept creeping up. Seems like the arduino might be only sending when it has a full buffer, and weirdly enough the issue with the 1 byte packets isnt showing up anymore. I'm poking around to try to figure out what exactly changed.

Comment: Also using serialPort1.ReadBufferSize I'm seeing the buffer is 4096, so not sure how I have 8192 bytes to read when thats double the buffer size.